# Apex Trigger not Firing on Mass/Bulk Update

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, update, bulk

I'm having an issue where my Apex Trigger only works when updating one Contact at a time. It doesn't work too well when doing a bulk or mass update and I don't quite understand why. My trigger checks to see if a set of fields have changed, and if so, it makes an API call.

```
// any Contact that has the Level of Access field (Level_of_Access__c) as either Educator or Administrator 
// will be created in WordPress and their curriculum synced. 
trigger CurriculumManagementTrigger on Contact (after update) {

    // Check the curriculum fields for changes
    Map<String, String> changeset = new Map<String, String>();
    
    // Set a flag so we know whether to send the API call
    Boolean makeCall = false;

    // The curriculum fields we need
    // Rosh_Hodesh__c, Shevet__c, RH_Sexuality__c, Shevet_Sexuality__c, B_nai_Mitzvah__c, Camp__c, Tzelem__c, Responsive__c, Sample_Curriculum__c
    // Do not run if we're in a batch or future method. We are not allowed to make future method calls from these contexts.
    if ( System.IsBatch() == false && System.isFuture() == false && Test.isRunningTest() == FALSE) { 

        for ( Contact c : Trigger.new ) {
            
            if ( c.Level_of_Access__c == 'Educator' || c.Level_of_Access__c == 'Administrator' ) {
                
                for ( Contact c_old : Trigger.old ) {
    
                    // Curriculum Fields - if any curriculum management fields changed, then we should make the call. 
                    // Or if the contact did not previously have a level of access and now it does, we should sync any checkboxes that were already checked.
                    if ( String.valueOf( c_old.Level_of_Access__c ) != String.valueOf( c.Level_of_Access__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Rosh_Hodesh__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Rosh_Hodesh__c ) 
                        || String.valueOf( c.Shevet__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Shevet__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.RH_Sexuality__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.RH_Sexuality__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Shevet_Sexuality__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Shevet_Sexuality__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.B_nai_Mitzvah__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.B_nai_Mitzvah__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Camp__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Camp__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Tzelem__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Tzelem__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Responsive__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Responsive__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Sample_Curriculum__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Sample_Curriculum__c )
                        || String.valueOf( c.Heart_to_Heart__c ) != String.valueOf( c_old.Heart_to_Heart__c )
                       
                       ) {
                           
                           // Personal Fields
                           changeset.put( 'cell', c.MobilePhone );
                           changeset.put( 'email', c.Email );
                           changeset.put( 'first_name', c.FirstName  );
                           changeset.put( 'last_name', c.LastName  );
                           
                           // Contact ID field
                           changeset.put( 'id', c.Id );
                           
                           changeset.put( 'rosh_hodesh', String.valueOf( c.Rosh_Hodesh__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'shevet', String.valueOf( c.Shevet__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'rh_sexuality', String.valueOf( c.RH_Sexuality__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'shevet_sexuality', String.valueOf( c.Shevet_Sexuality__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'bnai_mitzvah', String.valueOf( c.B_nai_Mitzvah__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'camp', String.valueOf( c.Camp__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'tzelem', String.valueOf( c.Tzelem__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'responsive', String.valueOf( c.Responsive__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'sample', String.valueOf( c.Sample_Curriculum__c ) );
                           changeset.put( 'hearttoheart', String.valueOf( c.Heart_to_Heart__c ) );
                           makeCall = true;
                    }
                }
                
                // Grade
                // changeset.put( 'grade', c.Grade__c );
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( makeCall == true ) {
    
        // Add our Key
        changeset.put( 'key', 'XXXX' );
        
        changeset.put( 'update', 'true' );
        
        // Turn our map into JSON
        String changesetJSON = JSON.serialize( changeset );
        
        // Call our web service
        CurriculumManagementService.curriculumManagementPOST( changesetJSON );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic problem. For each contact in the `new` collection, you're looking at all the contacts in the `old` collection. That's why it works for one but not for more than one.

A Typical logic for what you want to do looks like this

```
for (Contact c : trigger.new) {

        //Only process contacts that are changed
        if ((c.Level_of_Access__c == 'Educator' || c.Level_of_Access__c == 'Administrator') && 
            (trigger.oldMap == null ||
                (c.someField != trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).someField ||
                 c.someOtherField != trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).someOtherField ))) {

           //Do Something
        }

    }
```

The above is a contrived example (and should be optimized), but you can see how you have to grab *the correct* contact from `trigger.oldMap` (a map version of `Trigger.old` giving access to the "old state" record data by ID) before you can compare to see whether the value changed

Comment: You need to use Trigger.oldMap for this, right?

Comment: This is what I get for a hasty copypasta. Thanks Phil